# Modular form weight 0

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is an entire modular form of weight 0 must be a constant? In particular, does a function defined on the upper half  plane that is analytic everywhere, including $i\infty$, imply boundedness? Can we use Liouville or Little Picard on a modular form, even though it is only defined on upper half plane? Thank you for helping me get a grasp of these basic concepts.

Comment: A modular form should be regarded as a holomorphic function on the compact Riemann surface $\mathcal{H}^*/\Gamma$, which is $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ together with $\infty$. Open mapping theorem would then force it to be constant.

Comment: Analytic everywhere including infinity is basically synonymous with "bounded."

Comment: On the other hand, note that boundedness on upper half plane does not imply constant in general.